# Inconsistent widths when transforming scale

Tags: css, css-transforms

Why are the two rectangles below different widths?

The first one is:

- 1% width
- 50x scale

The second one is:

- 100% width
- .5x scale

1 * 50 = 50 and 100 * .5 = 50, no?

```css
body {
  margin: 10px 30px;  
}
#box {
  width: 439px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.line {
  height: 10px;
  transform-origin: left;
}
#example1 {
  width: 1%;
  transform: scaleX(50);
  background-color: red;
}
#example2 {
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(.5);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'>
  <div id="example1" class="line"></div>
  <div id="example2" class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In chrome, it is way off

Comment: I think it is because 50% of 439px is 219px (rounding down to the nearest pixel) whereas 1% of 439px looks like it becomes 4px and (so 50 times = 200px). Because of this there is a 19px difference in size. Try setting a multiple of 100 as base size and they should become equal. (**Edit:** Well, almost. There is still a small difference and I don't know why).

Comment: I have a feeling this is something to do with margins...but it's interesting.

Comment: Ok, just found that in Chrome setting a multiple of 100 causes a small difference because of `border` on parent because due to the `box-sizing`, the content gets only x * 100 - 2px as 100% (like stated in Wes Foster's answer). The main issue is with pixel size calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in Chrome, this behavior seems to be because of how the  pixel equivalent of the percentage value is calculated.

- The size of `#example1` is 1% of 437px<sup>+</sup> which is exactly 4.37px but it seems like Chrome (and possibly other browsers) round this value to the nearest whole number. Because of this rounding, when you scale it up 50 times the width becomes only 200px.
- When you increase the parent size to 459px, you can see that `#example1` line becomes 250px wide because 4.57 gets rounded up to 5px.
- The size of `#example2` is 437px (100%) and when this is scaled down to 0.5, the width becomes 218.5px. Any value that is less than 0.5 seems to be getting rounded down whereas anything that is equal to or above 0.5 gets rounded up and so here the width becomes 219px.
- Because of the above you could see a difference of  19px between the width of the elements. In the snippet I have added a few other lines with pixel values for reference. The green colored one is 218px wide, yellow is 200px, purple is 218.4px, chocolate is 219px and brown is 218.5px. You can see how the green and purple are same width while chocolate and brown are 1px wider.
- If you set the container width as a multiple of 100 then this problem goes away. Refer the second block in the snippet. Note that it still has a small deviation because of the `border` setting as 1% of 498px is 5px (so 50 times is 250px) but .5 times 498px is 249px. You can see that it matches perfectly if you remove the `border` (or the `box-sizing) and make the parent container's size a multiple of 100.

<sup>+  437px because even though we say 100%, the `border-width` on either side is excluded to `box-sizing: border-box`.</sup>

```css
body {
  margin: 10px 30px;
}
#box {
  width: 439px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.line {
  height: 10px;
  transform-origin: left;
}
#example1 {
  width: 1%;
  transform: scaleX(50);
  background-color: red;
}
#example2 {
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(.5);
  background-color: blue;
}
#example3 {
  width: 218px;
  background-color: green;
}
#example4 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#example5 {
  width: 218.5px;
  background-color: brown;
}
#example6 {
  width: 219px;
  background-color: chocolate;
}
#example7 {
  width: 218.4px;
  background-color: purple;
}
#box2{
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'>
  <div id="example1" class="line"></div>
  <div id="example2" class="line"></div>
  <div id="example3" class="line"></div>
  <div id="example4" class="line"></div>
  <div id="example5" class="line"></div>
  <div id="example6" class="line"></div>  
  <div id="example7" class="line"></div>
</div>

<div id='box2'>
  <div id="example1" class="line"></div>
  <div id="example2" class="line"></div>  
</div>
```

---

Contrary to what I had mentioned earlier (in comment and answer), the blur at the end of the scaled-down line is probably not because of layer differences because in both cases the lines will get only a rendering layer and no graphics layer. This blur is something that I am not able to explain right now.

You can read more about the layer creation, compositing and rendering in the below article:

- [GPU Accelerated Rendering in Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome)

Comment: So, to add a bit of purpose to the question. I'm trying to improve animation performance by going from modifying the width of an element to making the element's width a fixed value and then modifying the scaleX of the element. Is the only acceptable way to do this through using 100% width and scaling down?

Comment: @SeanAnderson: I can't say with certainty but I would recommend 100% width and scaling down because scaling happens in a graphic layer which seems to able to handle sub-pixel rendering (refer the blurred area that I mentioned in answer) whereas 1% width calculation happens at the rendering layer itself which doesn't seem to able to handle sub-pixel values.

Comment: Yep I agree! Not very intuitive, but it all makes sense once it's laid out.

Comment: Yea true @SeanAnderson. I have been reading about the rendering stuff for a week or so and this seems to fit. I will edit answer if I manage to find any more info from authoritative source.